# Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I'm currently making an app for a class. My partner and I are both using separate android tablets and when I upload my application from my computer onto my tablet and go to the map, it works. When my partner uploads the application from his computer to his tablet, the map screen shows up blank. I then uploaded the application from my laptop to his tablet and the map showed up just fine. What is the problem here? Is there something going on with my friends laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have generated a map API key (in xml layout) for your computer's debug certificate, not your partner's. Your source code has one key for one computer, but you have 2 computers with 2 different debug certificates.

I had this problem on my two computers and solved it by copying android's debug keystore from one computer (where it's working) to the other one - it's .android\debug.keystore (or similar) in your user directory.